# Prove $\sup(S \cup T) = \max\{\sup S, \sup T\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I found the solution online but I don't understand one part.

Let $M$ be an upper bound for $S \cup T$.

Then by definition, $M \geq \sup S$ or $M \geq \sup T$.

And the next line is just

$\sup(S \cup T) \geq \max\{\sup S,\sup T\}$

but I thought $\sup S \leq \max\{\sup S, \sup T\}$ and $\sup T \leq \max\{\sup S, \sup T\}$

because isn't the definition of $\max\{a,b\}=n$,  $n\geq a$ or $n\geq b$?

Comment: You have $M \ge \sup S$ **and** (not or) $M \ge \sup T$. Hence $M \ge \max(\sup S, \sup T)$.

Comment: and then because Sup(S U T) is the least upper bound M $\geq$ Sup (S U T) $\geq$ max{SupS, supT}

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: One more thing, Since M $\geq$ sup S and M $\geq$ sup T, wouldnt that imply M = max (SupS, SupT)?

Comment: No. Note that $10 > 1$ and $10 > 2$ but $10 \neq \max(1,2)$. (Take $S=\{1\}, T-\{2\}$.)

Comment: thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $\max\{a,b\}$ is “the largest among $a$ and $b$”. That is
$$
\max\{a,b\}=
\begin{cases}
a & \text{if $a\ge b$} \\
b & \text{if $b>a$}
\end{cases}
$$
In particular
$$
\max\{a,b\}\ge a \textbf{ and }\max\{a,b\}\ge b
$$

After this, if $M$ is an upper bound of $S\cup T$, then it is both an upper bound of $S$ and of $T$. Therefore it is larger than both $\sup S$ and $\sup T$. Therefore
$$
M\ge\max\{\sup S,\sup T\}
$$
Finally you have to show that $m=\max\{\sup S,\sup T\}$ is the *least* upper bound.

Suppose $m=\sup S$; then, if $\varepsilon>0$, there is $x\in S$ with $x>m-\varepsilon$. Since $x\in S\cup T$, we have that $m-\varepsilon$ is not an upper bound of $S\cup T$. Similarly if $m=\sup T$.